# Inspect document doesn't show anything, Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In my Excel 2010 workbook I wen through File > Info > Check for Issues > Inspect document. But as it's shown following, it doesn't show anything. Why?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the add-in enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the Office installation. I repaired it and problem is solved.